# Correct way to use logs in java?

Tags: java, logging

I have been consulting the internet in search of information on how to manage logs in Java, but I see many developers that manage it differently, both using external libraries such as **Apache Log4j** etc. as well as those that come in the core of Java.

Is it a question of personal preferences of the developer to use an external library or use the ones provided by **Java**?

I'm pretty new in **logs**, is there any website or documentation that can provide me with a good understanding of **logs** and witch is the correct way to use them?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple logging framework in the Java ecosystem and the choice of a particular one depends on on your requirements and preferences.
If you are creating a library to be used by others, you may want to take a look as slf4j (https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) which decouples the logging code from the choice of the logging framework.

Comment: I will go and check that out.